# Copy file from one server path to another showing access denied

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

Copy file from one server path to another showing access denied though I have given full access.

> Error:System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is
>   denied. at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String
>   maybeFullPath) at System.IO.File.InternalMove(String sourceFileName,
>   String destFileName, Boolean checkHost)

I have tried give security access to the required folder

```
string sourceFile = "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/MATS_History_Load_App/Python_Scripts/MATSUpgrade.xlsx";

string destinationFile = "//192.xxx.47/Mats/mats_test/MATSUpgrade.xlsx";

// To move a file or folder to a new location:
System.IO.File.Move(sourceFile, destinationFile);
```

Important: The application is hosted on IIS

Comment: please add some of the helping information like hosting environment in the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

given there is no access problem with the identity of your code's process:

this works perfectly well out of the box, try to replace slash with Backslashs and use the `@` before the path string:

```
string sourceFile = @"C:\temp\test.txt";
string destinationFile = @"\\fileshare\users\xy\prime.txt";
System.IO.File.Move(sourceFile, destinationFile);
```

otherwise in service or web hosting scenarios, you need to consider the access rights of your executing identity:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/207671/how-to-access-network-files-from-iis-applications

Comment: also try to map the network share to a windows letter drive, and copy to that drive letter path, if this behaves differently.

Comment: @Trendycuz is your code hosted on IIS or other web host / service  and therefor executed with an account other than yours? check with the IUSR / IIS_IUSRS / WAS / network service account.

Comment: it is hosted on IIS with   IIS_IUSRS

Comment: @Trendycuz this information is very important, it was missing in the question. this means of course that the owner/identity of the hosting process needs access on the network share. there are tons of information regarding this common problem with either runnning with another identity or using delegation which can be more challenging. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/207671/how-to-access-network-files-from-iis-applications

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, if you want to modify or access the network share folder. You should make sure you have choose the right application pool identity permission firslty. If you use the Network Service account as the identity, you still need to add enough permission on the shared folder, Since Network service and local system both appear on the network as the computer account (DOMAIN\computer$).

Normally, we will select the network servcie.

Details, you could refer to below steps:

1.Open the IIS management console, select the right application pool and click the advanced settings.

[image]

2.Select the identity and modify the account to networkserivce

[image]

3.Right cick the computer and click the property, you will find your computer name as below:

[image]

4.Go to your shared folder server, right click the folder and click property. Then you could add your server's account to it like this (Domain\Servername$)

[image]