# Access to path is denied in Production, works in Dev

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

This is frustratingly weird.  I'm suddenly getting this error in Production, but not locally in development.

Specs:

- .Net Core 3.1
- IIS 10

```
Access to the path '\\[network share]\Files\Video' is denied.
```

It occurs when this method is called:

```cs
        public Task<bool> UploadAsync()
        {
            if (request.Metadata.ChunkIndex == 0)
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists(request.Metadata.UploadLocation))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(request.Metadata.UploadLocation);
                }
            }
            
            var fixedFileName = FileManager.FixFileName(request.Metadata.FileName);

            var basePath = Path.Combine(request.Metadata.UploadLocation, PARTIALS);
            if (!Directory.Exists(basePath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(basePath);
            }

            var filePath = Path.Combine(basePath, fixedFileName);
            AppendToFile(filePath, request.File);

            return Task.FromResult(true);
        }
```

... and this line is called:

```cs
Directory.CreateDirectory(request.Metadata.UploadLocation)
```

It seems like it's due to some missing permission with IIS and the web application, since it works when I run the application in IISExpress.

And this is important, the application in both cases is pointing to the **same network share location** to drop the video file.

So it seems like any permissions on the network share folder is correct, but IIS can't access it.  That's my theory, but my network administrator says he hasn't changed anything with the application's app pool, so I don't have any other ideas.

Any ideas what is causing this issue?

Comment: "suddenly" as it worked in production for long time and stopped? That is very hard to believe as generally this code would not work... In any case you need to add details on whether your app uses some sort of impersonation and what account your app pool runs under and what permissions that netowrk share has.

Comment: When you run your app from visual studio, the web server runs as you. When IIS runs a web site, by default it uses an account that is local to that server. If you want to give a service network access, you need to run the web server as a user with that permission.

Comment: What account is the app pool running as?

Comment: Is it possible that `fixedFileName` is blank?

Comment: To all, I'm contacting the network admin to get this to work.  I don't know what permissions the server account has, but he's told me he's given it full control and it still isn't working.  We are currently still trying some things.

Comment: I will check on the `fixedFileName` value, but that code hasn't changed.  Yes it did work a week ago and it suddenly started throwing this exception.  Still checking.

Comment: Got it fixed.  The network admin added the app pool user to the network share folder and it all works now.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description and error codes, it seems this is related with permission issue.

To solve this issue, I suggest you could firstly modify the IIS application pool identity with a user which have the enough permission to access the network share and try again. If this is working well, this is related with the application pool identity account permission.

More details about how to modify the application pool identity permission, you could refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57487500/7609093).

Comment: Yes, I too believe it's an app pool identity issue and the network admin is looking into it.